# Menu with categories like MATE/Cinnamon Desktop Enviroment

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I have a question about menu with categories.

You can see this menu here: [image: http://linux.inf.ua/mint.png]

Does OS X Mountain Lion support somekind of this menu?

Comment: Are you simply looking for a "start menu" type UI for OS X or are you looking to run an entirely different interface instead of Finder? Good use of a picture, BTW - that helps narrow down what you seek immensely.

Comment: @bmike I want see menu with categories like on this picture :) this feature will be very useful:) only menu with categories, not another desktop enviroment

Answer (score 1):

While it does not pop UP from the bottom of the screen (rather it sits in the menu bar, top-right side of the screen) XMenu works VERY well:

http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html

(scroll down to the bottom of that screen to find the download link)

It's freeware and has been working great for me for a few years. It is completely customizable, quick and uses few system resources.

Comment: The place of menu is unnecessary. I mean that I want categories for applications in menu like on picture that I added to post. Thank you for Xmenu, I will try it!